# how can i set a function who runs after 24 hours of his call in php?

Tags: php

I'm working on a web application using php for treatment and PDO (mysql) for database, it is for the management of a game that I play with my friends (stocking everyone's money,do some calculations for paying taxes and it depend with every one,selling stuff between players,...) I'm working actually on the auction sale and what I want to do is that when a auction sale is started automatically a counter start counting so if 24 hours pass without been interrupted by another player you will buy the thing that means  that it will be a treatment and some changes in the database for example you will lose some money, but if someone put more than you even if you had just 1 hour left to buy it will restart the 24 hours and do the same things but with different parameters for example the other person that will lose the money not you and not the same amount of money...
So I searched in the web I found the function sleep but I feel like it will not work as i want what i want is some thing that runs in the background so the user can do other things while the 24 hours are passing and even if no one is online the 24 hours will still pass in the server.
informations : the server is linux ,every person who put a new price is registered in the database with those informations (id_person,price,date and time).

Comment: You seem to keep the data already, so just run a cron job to run every x minutes / hours that will pull the data of the ones that have been running for 24 hours, and process accordingly.

Comment: Use cron job as said before, but insert something into the DB when someone made a bid. So when your crob job does it's thing it will check the bids and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cron to make check every time you want
For example this is for every minutes : * * * * * path_to_php php_file

Comment: can you please tell me more about this? like it runs in the background ? the user still can use the web site ? and even if nobody is here it will still running ? and what about stoping it? if like i said someone else putted a higher price i want the first function to stop so i can run the new one. thank you for the answer

Comment: This will run in background

Comment: See here for more details : https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/

Comment: thank you i totaly forgot about this question, the problem is resolved exactly as you said.

Answer (score -1):

You can use sleep function to wait a defined time and then execute the rest of the code. To wait 24 hours :

```
sleep(60*60*24);
```